# How to read Xmx and Xms values from standalone.conf using CLI?

Tags: jboss, jvm, jboss7.x

How can I check the values of Xmx, Xms, and other JVM values, which are in standalone.conf, using the CLI?

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /core-service=platform-mbean/type=memory:read-resource(recursive=true,proxies=true,include-runtime=true,include-defaults=true)
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "heap-memory-usage" => {
                "init" => 3246391296L,
                "used" => 381631592L,
                "committed" => 3111124992L,
                "max" => 3111124992L
            },
            "non-heap-memory-usage" => {
                "init" => 2555904L,
                "used" => 80962112L,
                "committed" => 90963968L,
                "max" => 1317011456L
            },
            "object-name" => "java.lang:type=Memory",
            "object-pending-finalization-count" => 0,
            "verbose" => true
        }
    }
```

I need this values: JAVA_OPTS="-Xms**3096m** -Xmx**3096m** -XX:MetaspaceSize=**256m** -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=**512m** -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  These files, which live outside of the configuration directory, are native batch type files.  That's why there is a `standalone.conf` and a `standalone.conf.bat` - they are O/S dependent.  The CLI interacts with `standalone.xml` (or the other standalone configuration files) which is the O/S independent configuration.